# Swifter HTTP library runs on localhost simulator , but not working on real iPhone device

Tags: ios, swifter

I am using Swifter 1.5.0 http library , https://github.com/httpswift/swifter.  I am using this code to initialize

```
enter code here
import Foundation
import Swifter
class Server {
      var server: HttpServer
      init() { 
      server = HttpServer() 
}
 
func start(portnumber:UInt16 ) {
    server["hello"] = {
        .ok(.htmlBody("You asked for....mjkkkh\($0)"))
        
    }
    
    do {
          try server.start(portnumber)
      print("_______my ip_______Server has started at port \(try server.port())")
    } catch {
      print("_______my ip_______Server start error: \(error)")
    }
  }
  }
```

and into my view controller viewDidload, I started the HTTP by :

```
 let server = Server()
 server.start(portnumber: 8080)
```

It works well by testing on similar , calling this url: http://192.168.1.3:8080/hello , where 192.168.1.3 is the IP of my simulator. However , when I need into really iPhone device, I got new IP as 192.168.1.22, but when calling this url http://192.168.1.22:8080/hello , I get error message "Could not send request".

NB

- real device IP is correct. I ping this IP while device connected, it is sucesfull. If turned Wifi OFF, ping fails.